# How to ignore not changed files to "git commit" in PhpStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

I have a new branch from dev, make some changes and want to commit and push, when i press commit there are all files of project, changed and identical, all... How can I exclude not changed files? (PhpStorm 2018.1, Ubuntu 16.04)
[image]

```
git status
```

shows that all files are modified too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, i noticed, that the files were with a modified permission, so I exclude they with command 
`git config core.filemode false`

Answer (score 2):

It's because of encoding or different line endings, maybe someone uses ISO... and the next guy UTF-8, one linux and one windows.
For the line endings there's a setting in .gitconfig named *autocrlf*.

For the encoding you should all have the same one activated.
Check by rightclicking on the project and Ressource-Text Encoding.

If you don't want to include *single* files in a commit you can right-click on them and "replace with head revision" or something.

Comment: Related issue on JetBrains tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175120 - feel free to give it a vote